# Moment js not supporting for IOS for Date

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, datetime

When I try to use this moment for a date having an issue with IOS it's not getting reflected as expected, but on desktop and Android the date is displayed. in IOS its showing as "Invalid date"

```
{(this.state.apidata.length > 0 ? (this.state.apidata[0].startdate ? moment(this.state.apidata[0].startdate).locale((this.state.Language === 'English' ? 'en' : 'ar')).format("MMM YYYY") : moment(this.state.projectData.ProjectStartDate).locale((this.state.Language === 'English' ? 'en' : 'ar')).format("MMM YYYY")) : moment(this.state.projectData.ProjectStartDate).locale((this.state.Language === 'English' ? 'en' : 'ar')).format("MMM YYYY"))}
```

Tried with _monthsShort but it's raising an error

Comment: So what do you pass as argument? What is `this.state.apidata[0].startdate`?

Comment: "StartDateEN": "Dec 2022" , "EndDateEN": "Dec 2022", We are getting this from API

Comment: You should be passing Moment the date format when you construct the dates. Your format is not standard, and what is probably happening is that Safari does not recognize them.

Comment: And you probably should not be using Moment anyway.

Comment: Well that is `StartDateEN`, not `startdate`. What is `this.state.apidata[0].startdate`?

Comment: So could you please elaborate on how to fix it, so it would be better?

Comment: [Moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Comment: This is coming from API  setstate as apidata an array for the date @trincot.

Comment: I can only repeat: what is `this.state.apidata[0].startdate`? I am not asking where it comes from. It is irrelevant. I'm asking what that *value* is. So far you've given the value of a `StartDateEN` property. That is not what you have in the code.